# C# search form with database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a registeration form for new students and I need to have a datagridview with a textbox and a button above the datagridview to search students by studentID.I tried this code, but it didn`t work

```
 private void txtsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: You haven't provided the connection string or the SQL... Re-read some examples and follow them to the letter.

Comment: It exactly says: The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'. @dbugger

Comment: Pretty clear message -- you haven't provided the SQL Select statement to the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a couple things: The connection string to the database and a Select statement. You should do this code in a button click event rather than a click event on a textbox. Here is a better approach:

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from students where 
          studentId = " + txtSearch.Text, "Your connection string here");
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;            
    }
```